# Click Enter in TextBoxes for Runnig Button in Winrt?

Tags: textbox, windows-runtime, acceptbutton

How can I do that;

Click Enter in TextBoxes for Runnig Button in Winrt?

I remember that textbox's AcceptReturn property doing it but for doing it we were changing forms' AcceptButton property in System.Forms but there is no property named AcceptButton.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is one property out of the box, but I will probably add an attached property or two to the WinRT XAML Toolkit to add that feature. For now you can either do the same thing - implement an attached property that will do it for you or simply listen for key events on the form manually and handle the Enter key the same way you handle the button.

Comment: Thank you Filip, I did it :)